# Electron using screen sharing through Electron webview (loadUrl())

Tags: electron, jitsi, screensharing

I developed a small Electron Dekstop application that handle's login on my webapp and then "load" the webapp through an Electron loadUrl().

We already implemented Jitsi meet in that webapp (with specific UI etc). Everything works fine except the screen sharing.
(The first development was years ago, and since Electron did not allowed custom chrome extension we just didn't bother to make the screen sharing work).

Since then a lot of changes happened and it seems like this project managed to make it work.

I am aware of the solution that allows electron to use the jitsi screen sharing through @jitsi/electron-sdk but i'm wondering whether a solution exists in my case (AKA Jitsi not being implemented directly in Electron, but through a loadUrl()).

Is there a chrome extension that I could add to my electron project allowing chromium to get the JitsiMeetElectron.obtainDesktopStreams function ?

Or is the only solution to implement from scratch jitsi in our Electron project ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get any further?

Comment: check my answer may it work in your case

Answer (score 0):

use desktopCapturer to share the screen in the load URL
add this code in **app.whenReady().** this will automatically screen the first available screen

```
session.defaultSession.setDisplayMediaRequestHandler((request, callback) => {
    desktopCapturer.getSources({types: ['screen']}).then((sources) => {
        callback({video: sources[0]});
     });
 });
```

but if you want to select a particular screen you need to implement your own desktop picker dialog [desktopCapturer](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/desktop-capturer) in Electron.
for that instead of passing sources[0] in callback emit an electron event which show all the available screen and then return your particular source id and pass it to `callback({video: sources[id]});`

it may be not work in the case of google meet screen sharing because Google does not allow this but it works in my case when I have to load [bigbluebutton video conferencing](https://bigbluebutton.org/) web app in electron through load URL